# HTML with an input tag isn't found by getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src =
        "../js/test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><input type = "button" value = "Click";></input></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the corresponding JavaScript file `test.js`

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
console.log(inputs.length);
```

and the value shown is 0.  Can anyone explain?

Comment: you are trying to get the element before it's loading to dom

Comment: Is that the whole JavaScript file? Also `<input>` is self-closing. The `</input>` is not necessary.

Comment: @putvande My understanding--correct me if I'm wrong--is that even with tags that are self-closing, it's good practice to close them somehow.  Like it's better to write `<br/>` even though `<br>` would work.  This is just what I've heard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the element before it's loading to DOM, to execute after elements are loaded move the script tag after the elements or add it within the [onload event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).

```
window.onload = function(){
   var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
   console.log(inputs.length);
}
```